# Questions with answers appearing despite having a no-answers filter set

Tags: bug, recent-activity, tag-filters, no-answers

As the title says I have a custom filter so I can browse questions by **recent activity** with **no answers**. Despite that sometimes a notification at the top of the list of questions appear that since I've refreshed **a new question fitting my criteria** has appeared. Yet when i click on the notification a question **with an answer** appears where I presume the recent activity was the answer added judging by the timestamps. Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the appropriate filter set and the question that slipped through the filter]

And yes I'm sure the filter was applied. Is this a bug?

Comment: questions with an answer score of zero or less are considered to be not answered. So it is not the answer count that makes it unanswered but the score.

Comment: and yet i have only ever seen answered questions when they are added to the top in this way

Comment: @rene That sounds like weird logic and isn't communicated (afaict) in the filter. Do you happen to know what is the purpose of that rule?  I wondered for a long time why I had questions with answers showing up in the filter.

Comment: Yep, it seems to work similar to the [Unanswered tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), in which case, the checkbox should probably be renamed to "Unanswered", although I never really liked that ambiguous wording ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: It is not weird logic, it is SE logic. Where we redefine what "no"  means. Or at least Atwood did, back in 2009.

Comment: Normative reference: https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/30/ok-now-define-answered/

Comment: @rene The thing is, the "Unanswered" tab is somewhat OK. But here, because it explicitly says "**No** answers" _and_ there's a checkbox right below it that says "No accepted answer", it's very confusing. I know I know, "don't shoot the messenger", but I'm just saying :-D